# How to resolve "Object not found!" error in codeigniter control

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, controls

I get an error in the following code:

```
if(count($q_cek_login->result())>0)
{
    foreach($q_cek_login->result() as $qck)
    {
                   
        if($qck->ID_JABATAN==1)
        {
            foreach($q_cek_login->result() as $qad)
            {
                $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'yesGetMeLogin';
                $sess_data['username'] = $qad->USERNAME;
                $sess_data['nama'] = $qad->NAMA;
                $sess_data['id_jabatan'] = $qad->ID_JABATAN;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }
                                
            header('location:'.base_url().'transaksi/pending');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "halo";
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost
> 11/05/13 13:45:53
> Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: you can use `redirect()` of codeigniter

Comment: Also, make sure that on the next following questions you can say "yes": you checked and installed right route for url above; 2. you implemented controller and action for the url. Try to load this page just typing url in browser by hand.

Comment: redirect give solution... thx u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
redirect(site_url('transaksi/pending'));
```

instead of

```
header('location:'.base_url().'transaksi/pending');
```

Also note that base_url does not contain index.php which site_url contains