# Object not found! redirect link codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

why i get the error :
my code :

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/logout">Log Out</a></li>
```

error :

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
11/05/13 17:20:15
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Comment: Are you sure you are having logout function in your welcome controller

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this answer to another one of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19783325/540162) solves the issue, since it seems to be **the exact same problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are chances

1. You can make this empty $config['base_url'] = '';
2. Check .htaccess in root folder with index.php file
3. Check mod_rewrite apache module is enabled

RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have used at your controller this instruction?

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```